# How do I read the value of a single child in Firebase Database?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, cocoa, firebase-realtime-database

I'm on ios and I need to read the value for "BitcoinAddress" in my firebase database and put that value (in my case 0x123456) into a variable (which I will then put in a label).

Heres my database:

```
coinview-mgn
 |Users
  |fSqYasH907dOVWIodaUoXHTSVRf1
   |BitcoinAddress: "0x123456"
   |ExchangeURL: www.coinsquare.com
```

And I need it to be able to change since the user will be able to update to value.

I tried doing this:

```
 var bitcoinAddressText = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    self.bitcoinAddressText = self.ref?.child("Users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).value(forKey: "BitcoinAddress") as! String  
    }
```

But I got a SIGABRT with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRDatabaseReference 0x604000a4ce10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key BitcoinAddress.'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `Bitcoin` your outlet? maybe a label ?

Comment: pls check you have remove Bitcoin IBOutlet in your code

Comment: "Bitcoin" is not an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Hero you go, you need to call getData()

```
do {
    let snapshot = try await databaseRef.child("counters/234").getData()
    return snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```